# $f+g \in \mathcal{L}^p$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu$ be a measure space and $p\in \{1,2\}$. Let $f, g \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega,\mu).$

Show that $f+g \in \mathcal{L}^p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Minkowski's inequality, $$\int_{\Omega}|f+g|^p d\mu \le \Big(\Big(\int_{\Omega}|f|^p d\mu\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\Big(\int_{\Omega}|g|^p d\mu\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big)^p< +\infty$$ as both $f,g \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega)$ and hence $f+g \in \mathcal{L}^p(\Omega)$